# Eclipse just runs forever in the middle of a program execution

Tags: java, eclipse

I observe a really weird behavior. I'm pretty sure there's a bug in my code, but Eclipse's behavior is so strange that I cannot figure anything out.

First, here's my code: http://pastebin.com/JCaW53GM.

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler's problem 96](https://projecteuler.net/problem=96), i.e., I'm trying to build a Sudoku solver using Knuth's Dancing Links. After a lot of preparation, this procedure is supposed to solve the problem:

```
    private static void search(int k) {
            System.out.println("start search");
            if (masterHeader.right == masterHeader) {
                    return;
            }

            // choose column
            Column c = new Column("");
            int s = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Column j = (Column) masterHeader.right; j != masterHeader;
                            j = (Column) j.right) {
                    if (j.size < s) {
                            c = j;
                            s = j.size;
                    }
            }

            // dancing links
            c.cover();

            for (Datum r = c.bottom; r != c; r = r.bottom) {
                    o[k] = r;
                    for (Datum j = r.right; j != r; j = r.right) {
                            j.column.cover();
                    }
                    System.out.println("before calling search(" + k + " + 1)");
                    search(k + 1);
                    r = o[k];
                    c = r.column;
                    for (Datum j = r.left; j != r; j = j.left) {
                            j.uncover();
                    }
            }

            c.uncover();
    }
```

Whenever I run the program, I get the following output:

```
start search
before calling search(0 + 1)
start search
before calling search(1 + 1)
start search
before calling search(2 + 1)
start search
before calling search(3 + 1)
start search
before calling search(4 + 1)
start search
before calling search(5 + 1)
start search
before calling search(6 + 1)
start search
before calling search(7 + 1)
start search
before calling search(8 + 1)
start search
```

After that---nothing. There is no error, no overflow, Eclipse just continues running forever. I have no clue at all what this means. I'm pretty sure the fact that it stops at search(9) has something to do with the many nines in my code. But there is no error, and I'm at a loss.

Can anybody enlighten me? What does Eclipse want? What did I do wrong?

**Edit:** Gaaah! I completely overlooked that last "start search" of the output. That was what was confusing me. Guess I was just too tired... anyway, sorry to everyone for bothering you. Yes, it is clearly just a simple case of infinite loop. I hope I'll be able to debug that myself.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in the post, instead of just linking to it.

Comment: Sounds like you think it might be an Eclipse issue... so did you try running it from command line or DrJava(or any lightweight Java editor) instead ?

Comment: It's called an infinite loop. You have a loop termination condition that's not being satisfied so your loop continues to execute indefinitely. This is when you fire up your debugger.

Comment: Run in Debug mode, and pause the program when it appears to be stuck.  You will then be able to investigate and singlestep through the program to learn what happens.

Answer (score 2):

`r != c;` is an expression that only makes sense if you're talking about the exact same instance of an object.  Since both `r` and `c` are `Datum` objects, it will not evaluate to `true` unless they are the **exact** same instance.

What you probably want to do is define `.equals` instead on the `Datum` class.  Then, you can call `!r.equals(c)` instead.

You could also do with a rename of those variables, as `row` and `column` are far more straightforward than `r` and `c`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that is actually the idea. It is simply a vertical list, and the loop should stop when it arrives back at the "topmost" element. And yes, I'll probably rename the variables. At the moment, the code is more or less just one-to-one the pseudocode from Knuth's paper.